# split problem between \left( and \right)

Tags: amsmath, align

I have this equation, and strangely enough I can not split the equation from somewhere in between `\left(` and `\right)` If I use the `\\` to split the equation after `\right)` then it works, I did not really get why?

Or the problem is changed to a simpler one...

```
\begin{split}
\left(
a \\
b
\right)
```

which is is the problem.

Comment: You can't use `\left` in one alignment line and `\right` in another one. Please, try making your example self contained, from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`, giving the needed definitions of `\mat` and `\vect`.

Comment: Ok that is clear, I did not understand why?

Comment: Because TeX knows only how to typeset single line formulas (but it is able to align many of them) and `\left` must have a matching `\right` in the formula.

Comment: so even on lines, right and left should match? You can not split them with 'split'

Comment: See the question I linked as duplicate